# MS Word - How to format numbers in table formulas with apostrophe?

Tags: microsoft-word

MS Word - How to format numbers in table formulas with apostrophe?

I want to format my numbers like that:

19'000

I tried something like that in NUMBER FORMAT dropdown:

```
#'##0
```

or

```
#"'"##0
```

There is an error, and nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Using a format such as `\#'##0` to get 19000 to appear as 19'000 suggests that you want the ' to be used as a "thousands separator character". But that can only work if ' is set to be the "digit grouping symbol" in the Regional settings in Windows Control Panel (I'm assuming you're using Windows Word here). That *is* the default setting for German (Swiss), for example. If you have that setting, then there should be no error, but 19000 will appear as 19'000 and 19000000 will appear as 19'000'000.

If you want ' to appear as a thousands separator when ' is not set as the digit grouping symbol, things are more complicated. First, the normal Unicode U+0027 APOSTROPHE character, and many of the other "single quotation" characters, always have to be inserted in pairs. But if your font has Unicode U+02C8 MODIFIED LETTER VERTICAL LINE (`ˈ`), you may be able to use that. But then `\#ˈ##0` would give you `ˈ19000`, not `19ˈ000`. Further, the ˈ character would *always* appear, even if you wanted to format "19". ANd it would not replicate every 3 characters.

To deal with that, you would have to use a format string that varied depending on the length of the number that you wanted to format. e.g. if the number was 123, you might use `\#0`. If it was 1234, you might use `\#0ˈ000`. If it was 1234567, `\#0ˈ000ˈ000`, and so on. That can be done, but it isn't simple, probably tricky enough that you might want to find another approach. One reason why it isn't simple is that the result is not numeric, so things will probably go wrong if you try to use the result of the field in another calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps:

**Method 1**:

1. **Open** your document.
2. Click inside the document **where** you want to insert.
3. Press the "**Ctrl**" key and a **punctuation** key at the same time. It will give grave accent, **apostrophe**, caret, colon or tilde. The key symbols resemble the accent symbols. For example, press the "**Ctrl**" key and the **apostrophe** key to insert an acute accent symbol. Press the "Ctrl" key and the caret key to insert a circumflex symbol.
4. Press the letter key. The accented character appears.

**Method 2**:

1. Open Word.
2. Select the **Insert** tab on the Ribbon or click **Insert** in the **Menu bar**.
3. From the dropdown select **Symbol** option.
4. You may choose from the **limited** selection of symbols that appear or click **More** Symbols.
5. Select **symbol** and click on **Insert**.

**Method 3**:

1. Click on **Microsoft Office Button**, then **Word Options**.
2. Click **Proofing**.
3. Next **AutoCorrect Options**.
4. Click the **AutoFormat** As You Type tab.
5. **Select** or **clear** the check boxes for the options that you want to enable or disable.

To know what each option do, please visit this **[site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-automatic-formatting-as-you-type-1ed6b53c-018c-4de8-bb32-7ef4cd2c766b#bm1)** and click on **Office**.

Hope it helps.

Thank you.